# Like operator Range query

Tags: ms-access, sql-like

I am trying to design a simple query in which I want to select records from a table where the first letter of surnames lies within a single letter range.

The range is entered in the query as an expression like A-B which I call SurnameRange in the query table. Under the Surname criteria I have entered 'Like "SurnameRange*"

If I enter SurnameRange as A-B, or B-B or A-A, it produces 2 (out of 15) records beginning with A.What am I doing wrong?

---

Thanks for all previous answers. I have solved my problem with the BETWEEN operator
Nickoby

Comment: What type of database is this you are running the query on?

Comment: I am using an Access 2007 (originally 2003) database under Windows 10

Comment: Your situation might be easier to understand if you switched the query from Design View to SQL View and show us the query's SQL. I wonder if you want this: `Like '[A-B]*'`

Comment: If you solved it, please post how as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using an Access 2007 database under Windows 10.

Thanks for all suggestions but I solved the problem by isolating the first character of the name in a query column and, from a sub-form on the initiating form, using two range letters entered there. Then in the query I used the BETWEEN operator to establish the records I wanted. 
I would like to regard this topic as now closed.

Comment: To close the question, accept your answer. (I think you have to wait some time before you can do that.)